# Load a lot of txt file inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

I know the function .load() of jQuery to load one text from a .txt file, but have a way to load a lot of .txt file inside a div?

I've tried to do this:

```
   for (i = 1;i<9;){
      $("#slide2 .wrapper").load(+i+".txt");
      i++;
   };
});
```

But it functions with image to do a gallery, but not with .txt...

My intention is to do something like a blog, where i can only put the .txt file in a directory and it be loaded automatically in my HTML.

Comment: Maybe a lot of txt fileS? What are you getting and what do you want to get? As I understand, you simply want to load all files into one div, but have some problem with that?

Comment: My browser is stopping when i try run this code... I don't know why... Because this i came here to ask... But your solution below seems me a good solution!

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and (by extension) jQuery are client side web technologies and for security reasons are not allowed natively to access local files on the users computer.

You'll have to place that text file on a server and give the `.load()` function a URL that points to the file.

---

Ah, missed something... [It looks like you are trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bo21.png) to load multiple files... In this case, again, I would recommend creating some magic on the server. Something like one PHP script that will [`glob('*.txt')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) all the files and [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) them in a loop creating on long stream of text...

Comment: Not necessarily: [FileReader Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader)

Comment: @ibu - not all of us have the luxury of ignoring non major browsers `:'(`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
for (i = 1;i<9;){
      $.get(+i+".txt", 
            function(res){
               $("#slide2 .wrapper").text($("#slide2 .wrapper").text() + res);//I expect here that you have a plain text in .txt files and want to see it like a text 
           });
      i++;
};
```

This should load all files and **append** them to `$("#slide2 .wrapper")` content.

In case of `.load` you will get the last loaded file only as that function simply replaces content of `$("#slide2 .wrapper")` with a content of file being loaded. Please note that there is no guaranty that 1.txt will be loaded before 2.txt. It is possible that 2.txt will be loaded faster than 1.txt and content of 1.txt will be shown after the content of 2.txt.

If you want to keep an order, you can use code like this:

```
   getContent(1);// instead of for loop
});

function getContent(i) {
    $.get(+i+".txt",    
        function(res) {
           $("#slide2 .wrapper").text($("#slide2 .wrapper").text() + res);//I expect here that you have a plain text in .txt files and want to see it like a text          
           if(i < 9)
               getContent(i++);
        }
    );  
}
```

For reference: [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: It looks great!  I've just a beginner question: What is the "res" inside function()?  What it do?  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `res` will contain loaded content. See updated answer. There are two links to jQuery docs where everything is described in details. And if you want to work with jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/ is a site you can find all info about jQuery features.

Comment: Also, if you say browser stops working with your code- check your console (F12 in all browsers, in FF you may need to install firebug). Console should show you errors. Possibly you have no jQuery linked to your page and that is why `.load` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't know a whole lot about php but it should be pretty simple.

1. Create a new file but name it SomeFile.php.
2. Copy all your html script in exactly as you had it in the html file, but delete the jQuery for trying to load the contents of the file.
3. Insert this directly in your code where you want it to display, for instance in a `<div>`

   ```
   <?php 
       for($i=0;$i<9;$i++)
       {
           echo file_get_contents($i.".txt");
       } 
   ?>
   ```

This should run on any typical hosting service, or if self-serving make sure your server is php enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            url : i + ".txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#slide2.wrapper").append(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and your html should be:

```
<div id="slide2" class="wrapper"></div>
```